# Variable null si no está cargada en la base de datos, me muestre un mensaje

Tags: mysqli, php7

Estoy intentando hacer un sistema para una docente relacionando dos tablas una que es trabajos y otra ficha alumno.
No logro hacer que cuando en ficha alumno no este cargado el trabajo me muestre en el listado no entrego, definido en css como un cuadrado color rojo. La variable es $evaluacion

Les paso el Código, gracias

```
<?php
        $query = "SELECT * 
        FROM alumnos WHERE escuela_alumnos=$id AND grado_alumno=$idg
        ";
$aRes = $dbLink->query($query);
foreach($aRes AS $row) {
$nombre_alumno = $row["nombre_alumno"];
$id_alumnos = $row["id_alumnos"];
echo"
<tr>
<td>$nombre_alumno</td>
<td>\n";
$query = "SELECT * 
        FROM tareas WHERE escuela_tarea=$id AND grado_tarea=$idg AND trimestre_tarea='1'
        ";
$aRes = $dbLink->query($query);
foreach($aRes AS $row) {
$nombre_tarea = $row["nombre_tarea"];
$id_tarea = $row["id_tarea"];
echo"
<div class=\"entrega\">
  <div class=\"tarea\">$nombre_tarea</div>\n";
  
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM ficha WHERE escuela=$id AND grado=$idg AND trimestre='1' AND alumno=$id_alumnos AND 
tarea=$id_tarea";
$aRes = $dbLink->query($query);
foreach($aRes AS $row) {
$presento = $row["presento"];
$evaluacion = $row["evaluacion"];
echo"     
<div class=\"entrego\">\n";
if ($presento === null){
echo"
<div class=\"no\"></div>\n";    
}else{
echo"
<div class=\"si\"></div>\n";    
}
echo"
</div>
  <div class=\"nota\">$evaluacion</div>\n";
}
echo"     
</div>\n";
}
echo"
</td>
?>
```

Comment: si un alumno no presento.. hay un registro en ficha que tiene null? o no hay registro?

Comment: No sé a qué te refieres cuando dices que la variable en la que debemos fijarnos es `$evaluacion` cuando en el código verificas a `$presento`... Por otra parte, en lugar de 3 consultas, varias de ellas en bucles, podrías obtener todo en una sola consulta, usando `GROUP_CONCAT` y `GROUP BY` y luego trabajar los resultados. Una sola consulta es más rápida que `N` consultas, sobre todo si tienes tus tablas bien indexadas.

Comment: no hay registro en la tabla ficha

Comment: si la variable es $presento

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que ocurre exactamente? Pon un `var_dump($presento);` y revisa lo que imprime.

Comment: en los alumnos que presentaron el trabajo me pone string(1) "2" pero en el resto que no estan gargados en la tabla ficha no me pone nada

Comment: Es raro que no ponga nada, debe poner aunque sea una cadena vacía o null. Haz un debug de toda la fila poniendo un `var_dump($row);` Aunque los `foreach` de lectura son raros, no usas métodos `fetch`, ¿tienes una clase propia de consulta? Generalmente se usan métodos `fetch`

Comment: me pone esto en los alumnos que estan cargados en ficha

Comment: string(1) "2" array(8) { ["id_f"]=> string(1) "1" ["escuela"]=> string(1) "2" ["grado"]=> string(1) "1" ["alumno"]=> string(1) "3" ["trimestre"]=> string(1) "1" ["tarea"]=> string(1) "1" ["presento"]=> string(1) "2" ["evaluacion"]=> string(1) "2" }

Comment: pero si no está cargado el alumno en ficha porque no puedo pintar de rojo los trabajos entendiendo que no estan presentados

Comment: No sé que quieres decir con *los alumnos que está cargando en ficha* ¿?  Para que tu consulta trabaje tienes que tener un set de datos completo, con un determinado valor en `presento`, sea `null` o `0`  u otro. Si no te los trae revisa tus consultas. De todos modos, como te dije antes, deberías escribir una sola consulta para optimizar y simplificar tu código.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias por tu tiempo, un abrazo

Comment: debe ser que no me se explicar

Comment: soy nuevo en todo esto